# Нарушена логика построения SQL-запроса в DELPHI

Tags: sql, delphi, radstudio

При попытке вывести в DBGrid результат sql-запроса возникает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам sql-запрос выглядит так: 
`select Genious.*, count(Species.idG) as amount from Genious, Species where Genious.idG = Species.idG group by Genious.idG`

Скриншоты таблиц Базы Данных: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После "преобразования" sql-запроса мне удалось всё-таки выполнить задачи - в DBGrid появилась столбец с количеством видов в данном роде, но лишь только с другим столбцом idG, остальные столбцы вывести не получилось(см. начало)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SQL-запрос "преобразованный": `select Genious.idG, count(Species.idG) as amount from Genious, Species where Genious.idG = Species.idG group by Genious.idG`

Наведите на путь истинный, пожалуйста. Пытался через вычисляемые поля сделать, но не хватает знаний.

Comment: Любое поле выходного набора должно быть либо обёрнуто групповой функцией, либо входить в список выражения группировки. Однако из ВСЕХ полей выражения `Genious.*` этому условию отвечает только `Genious.idG`. Следует перечислить в списке вывода и в выражении группировки все реально нужные в выводе поля по отдельности. PS. И вообще, забудьте о звезде в запросах, кроме как в COUNT(*).

Comment: Всё работает! Я правильно понял: если мы используем агрегатные функции, то должны поле выходного набора выводить в список выражения группировки. Возьму за правило больше не использовать `*`, к сожалению, в методичке был именно запрос с .*, но без агрегатных функций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql запрос с использованием агрегатной функции должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
select ГруппируемыеПоля, Функция(Поле) from Таблица Group by ГруппируемыеПоля
```

Поэтому очевидно что `select Genious.*, count(Species.idG)` является ошибкой (т.к. Group by * ошибка синтаксиса)

Comment: *очевидно что `select Genious.*, count(Species.idG)` является ошибкой* - увы, но ошибкой является как раз это утверждение.